# Rails: How do you call 'update' from another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have an action (def do_some_stuff) but I would first like to update my post before doing so & if it's successful, it'll finishing "doing stuff"... Simple, right?

Here's my action

```
def do_some_stuff
  Rails.logger.debug "Post id is #{@post.id}"
  update #calls the update action
  ## does some stuff
end
```

Instead of updating, Rails is throwing me this error: "Required parameter missing: post" (meaning 'post' is nil, right?)

I'm getting the post id in my logger but for some reason it gives me that error.

To make things simpler, I decided to just try to call the update action in the 'do_some_stuff' action.. I'm using strong_params btw

How do I call the "update" action from another action?

Thank you in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I typed this on my phone so sorry in advance for any typos

---

my log:
Processing by PostsController#do_some_stuff as HTML
Parameters: id = 149

Comment: Just a tip for your future use of SO, if you're ever posting an error message (i.e `Required parameter missing: post`), post the entire error and at least the first few lines of the stack trace otherwise it's virtually meaningless. The stack trace shows where the error is being thrown.

Comment: @Mike that literally is the error.. It's a blank white page with that line..

Comment: hmpf, must be a rails 4 error or something to do with strong params that I don't know about. Either way, I'd be surprised if the logs didn't provide a more comprehensive error.

Comment: Why don't you update in the model from the controller you're in..?

Comment: @Adam Define the action in the model? I'll try that but I'm not sure how it'll work with strong_params..

Comment: @Adam I just tried.. Could you explain how you'd do it?

Comment: This is an error about strong parameters being required: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c49d959e9d40101f1712a452004695f4ce27d84c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L113

Comment: @Jon I think he means update the model rather than call a different controller action. That's what I suggested below.

Comment: @shioyama O ok.. Yep, I tried that..

Comment: Yeh I did mean that, why do you want to call a new action? If you want to keep code DRY create a private method.

Comment: @AdamWaite I will but I'm just trying to get this sorted out first

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling one action from another one. Instead, just call [`update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes) on the post:

```
def do_some_stuff
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    ## do some stuff
  end
end
```

If successful, `update_attributes` will return true and the "do some stuff" block will be executed.

This assumes that you already have a `@post` present. Usually you would get that in a `before_filter` block or method with a find: `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: True but that's the thing. I tried this & I'm still getting the same result.. Blank white page that reads the same error I posted in my question..

Comment: Sorry updated my answer. You have to first get the post somehow, probably by finding it.

Comment: Do you have a `params.require(:post)` somewhere?

Comment: I have that under private.. Because of the "require" part, I figured that I was getting that eror because Rails (or strong_params) thinks the "post" is nil but thats not the case..

Comment: Why is that not the case? I haven't personally tried the new strong parameters, but it would seem clear that `params.require(:post)` means that a `post` parameter is required, which presumably the request does not have. i.e. Does that make sense? I'd suggest reading up the topic.

Comment: Because the Post is not nil.. I'm seeing the post's params in my terminal using Rails.logger

Comment: What you are showing in the logger is the instance variable `@post`, what the error is talking about is the query parameter `params[:post]`. They are not the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. How do I pass in `params[:post]`?

Comment: `params` is what is sent in the request to the controller. You would typically pass `params[:post]` to the controller via a request from an html form. At this point this is beyond the scope of this question though.